# How to remove all strings from a given DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

I need to preprocess a column for machine learning in python. The column contains a series of 1s and 0s (which is the desired output), but there are some strings in there that needs to be removed ['PX7','D1', etc..]

I thought about using df.replace to replace the strings with np.nan and then using df.dropna() to remove it. I was wondering what is the standard way of doing this given that this is probably a very common preprocessing task.

Comment: Are there whole columns with string values? Or just a few cells?

Comment: You should show us sample data.  pandas does not like columns that are not all the same type.  So, are these string "0" and "1" cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df2 = df.where(df.isin([0,1]))
```

Or, convert to numeric to keep all numbers:

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Then you can use `dropna` the way you want (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df[df['col'].str.isdigit().fillna(True)]
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Second approch:

```
df[df['col'].isin([0,1])]
```

Comment: Got this error message
Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: So there is some values with not expected dtype there. You can investigate to find those values or try second approach in my answer.

Comment: Also can you print the dtype of the column?

Comment: You can use .astype(str) before using the first solution.

Comment: This worked, thank you! By the way, how do you check for all dtypes in a given df column? because .dtype only returns 1 answer

Comment: The point is that each column has one dtype. There is Object dtype to handle mixed type cols.